# how can I find the base R installation on ubuntu?

Tags: r

I installed both the Microsoft R Open and base R (CRAN) on my linux desktop. But I can't find where my base R was installed now. Is there a way I can find this out?

When I type `R` in terminal I get the following because `/usr/bin/R` points to my MRO install.

```
Microsoft R Open 3.2.3
Default CRAN mirror snapshot taken on 2016-01-01
The enhanced R distribution from Microsoft
Visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=722555 for information
about additional features.

Multithreaded BLAS/LAPACK libraries detected. Using 4 cores for math algorithms.
[Previously saved workspace restored]

> R.home()
[1] "/usr/lib64/MRO-3.2.3/R-3.2.3/lib/R"
```

I just want to know how I can access my CRAN R install again.

Thanks!

Comment: try searching in `/usr/lib/R/`. That is the location of my installation in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: I take that back. With `R.home()`, the returned location is `/usr/lib/R`, the home directory, whereas if I run `which R` in the terminal it returns `/usr/bin/R`. I can launch R by executing either `/usr/lib/R/bin/R` or `/usr/bin/R` - Each of those is a shell script which serves as a wrapper for the executable. The executable itself is at `/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R`. In your case, you may have to substitute `lib64` for `lib`